# SQL how to unset the @

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I try to update my DB by using an email as key,
but the @ sign in sql didn't work.

So, i tried also

```
""+':mail'+""';
```

So, how could i use the email with an @ sign as keyword?

```
$sql2 = 'UPDATE kunden SET anzahlung = 100 WHERE mail = :mail';

$stmt2 = $objDb->prepare( $sql2 );
$stmt2->bindParam(':mail',$_POST['payer_email']);

$stmt2->execute() ;
```

Comment: just use it. there is no difference

Comment: tried so many ways. maybe do you see another way to handle it.
i need it for my IPN listener and i'm gonna stuck

Comment: check the linked answer